# Android how to compare fragments?

Tags: android, fragment, slidingmenu

I have been using jfeinstein's [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). I am currently trying to find if a certain fragment is visible to the user. I first tried:

```
    if(mainfrag.isVisible()){
        Log.d("Frag","Main is visible");
    }else{
        Log.d("Frag","Main is NOT visible");
    }
```

Which always printed that the fragment was NOT visible. I then tried:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
Log.d("Frag","CurFrag: "+fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame).toString());

MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();
if(fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame) == mf){
    Log.d("Frag","This is Main");

}else{
    Log.d("Frag","This is NOT Main :(");

}
```

This prints

[image]

So I know that the `findFragmentById` will tell me the current fragment but I don't know how I can logically compare it so I can do things only if it is visible.

Comment: umm ! there is a method `
  public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {}`

Comment: If all your fragments are different classes, you could do a simple `instanceof` check. Alternatively, give every fragment a unique tag (and don't forget to supply it with each `FragmentTransaction`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have never dived into the details of SlidingMenu and couldn't tell you what's wrong in the first problem.

But in your second problem, you are comparing two different objects.

```
MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();
fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame) == mf
```

Here you create a new MainFragment, and try to compare it with a old instance. It can never be true. When comparing Objects, the address are compared. It will only return true if they are the same objects.

If you just want to check the class of object, use the following code:

```
Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
if(f instanceof MainFragment)
    // code here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the fragment by tag or by I'd

Get the fragment's view

Get window visibility on the view will provide visibility